# How to replace the strings begin with "alg to "dms::alg via gawk which is seen on Ubuntu16.04?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk, replace

As what said in the title, I want to replace `"alg_hash` to `"dms::alg_hash` , `"alg_sort` to `"dms::alg_sort` and etc via `awk` which actually uses `gawk` in `Ubuntu16.04`.

**Note**: the `dms` must be added between `"` and `alg`.

The code below almost achieve the said goal, but `"alg_hash` would be replaced by `dms::"alg_hash` other than `"dms::alg_hash`. How to make it work as expected?

```
awk '{
    sub(/\"alg_hash/, "dms::/&");
  }

  { print }
'
```

Comment: Why does it HAVE to be awk`? Did you consider `sed`? Show your attempt (awk-program) to solve it, so that we have some code to discuss.

Comment: @user1934428 Though Sed is not the first choice, if it can achieve the said goal. I can try it.   Pay attention to the text I recently added in the end of the question.

Comment: I'm not that much an awk specialist, but the backslash smells. You are inside a regex, and a quote does not have specific meaning, so IMO  there is no point in backslashing it. I would intuitively do something like `gsub(/"(alg_[a-z_]+)/, "\"dms::\\1")`

Comment: @user1934428 there are no backreferences to capture groups in POSIX awk and in an awk that provides the extension function `gensub()` such as GNU awk, THAT is the only `*sub()` function where backreferences are supported.

Comment: @John it's usually trivial to match the string you want to match (e.g. `.*` matches everything) but much harder to not match similar strings you do not want to match so when you only include matching, sunny-day, desirable strings in your example YMMV with how the solution you get will handle other cases.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thank you for pointing this out. So we need `gensub` here....

Comment: @user1934428 right, or GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` also provides a kind of backreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this input:

```
$ cat file
"alg_sort
"alg_hash
```

Using an awk that provides the extension function `gensub()`, e.g. GNU awk:

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/"(alg)/,"\"dms::\\1",1)}' file
"dms::alg_sort
"dms::alg_hash
```

or using any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/"alg/){$0="\"dms::" substr($0,RSTART+1)} 1' file
"dms::alg_sort
"dms::alg_hash
```

sed is usually more concise for simple substitutions on individual lines though, e.g. using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/"\(alg\)/"dms::\1/' file
"dms::alg_sort
"dms::alg_hash
```